# No exact matches in call to initializer with UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, canvas, cgcontext, unsafemutablepointer

I'm trying to make an unsafeMutablePointer with a context, and I'm getting the error "No exact matches in call to initializer". Not sure what is going on here. Working off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987442/drawing-pixels-on-the-screen-using-coregraphics-in-swift/34988630).

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

var pixels:Any?

if let data = context?.data
{
  pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>(data) // No exact matches in call to initializer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This answer* was written 5 years ago, which is too old in the Swift world.

I could not find a right answer searching with `No exact matches in call to initializer with UnsafeMutablePointer`, but there would be many articles about pointer handling when Swift changed the way how to convert the pointee type of pointers.

Please try this one:

```
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        var pixels: UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>? = nil

        if let data = context?.data {
            pixels = data.assumingMemoryBound(to: CUnsignedChar.self) //<-
        }
```

(You should better not use `Any` as far as you can.)

Comment: What's weird, is even though I'm drawing to a context, that if let statement never results in true, even when the program is calling a function to define pixels is on a timer. I set a break point inside that if, and it never lands there.